# How to find all the function of $f$ such that $\vec{\nabla}f=\vec{F}$?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Let $\vec{F}=[(2yz^2+\ln x+\sec^2(x+y)]\,\hat{i}+[2xz^2-2ze^{yz}+\sec^2(x+y)+\frac{y}{y^2+z^2}]\,\hat{j}+[4xyz-2ye^{yz}+\frac{z}{y^2+z^2}]\,\hat{k}$

How to find all the function of $f$ such that $\vec{\nabla}f=\vec{F}$?

I tried to integrate each component of $\vec{F}$, is this method correct?

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: Since $\nabla\times\nabla f=0$, we need that $\nabla\times F=0$ ($F$ must be curl-free) to be able to find an $f$ so that $\nabla f=F$. See [curl free field not neccessarily implies existence of scalar function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1684432)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\vec{F}=[(2yz^2+\ln x+\sec^2(x+y)]\,\hat{i}+[2xz^2-2ze^{yz}+\sec^2(x+y)+\frac{y}{y^2+z^2}]\,\hat{j}+[4xyz-2ye^{yz}+\frac{z}{y^2+z^2}]\,\hat{k}$$
First integration gives:
$$I_1=\int [(2yz^2+\ln x+\sec^2(x+y)]dx$$
$$I_1=2yz^2x+x \ln x - x + \tan (x+y)+ C_1$$
Where $c_1$ is all the functions that dosen't depend on $x$.

The second integral:
$$I_2=\int [2xz^2-2ze^{yz}+\sec^2(x+y)+\frac{y}{y^2+z^2}] dy$$
$$I_2=2xz^2y-2e^{yz}+\tan(x+y)+\frac 12 \ln ({y^2+z^2}) +C_2$$
Last integral gives:
$$I_3=\int [4xyz-2ye^{yz}+\frac{z}{y^2+z^2}]\, dz$$
$$I_3=2xyz^2-2e^{yz}+\frac 12\ln ({y^2+z^2})+C_3$$

Now you can deduce the function $f$:
$$f(x,y,z)=2xz^2y-2e^{yz}+\tan(x+y)+\frac 12 \ln ({y^2+z^2}) +x\ln x - x +C$$